# Submit InApp Products with New App for review in iTunes

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I have implemented InApp Purchase for new my App.
Tested it in Sandbox environment. Now ready to make a AppStore release.
I am not able to find following :

1. Where do I add In-App products for Production release. Can these
   be the same products that I added for sandbox in iTunes -> "MyApp"
   ->    Feature ?
2. How do I add those configured products to Submit for    review with
   my new App.(I am not able to see the option InApp
       Purchase with "+" sign even after creating a version and selecting
       the build-binary.) I have enabled In-app purchase in Project
       capabilities.
3. Also can I set my own price to In-app products ? Currently there's only one drop down with predefined set of prices while configuring a product.

I have already refered this link.
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnectInAppPurchase_Guide/Chapters/SubmittingInAppPurchases.html

Comment: Does you app already have inApp purchases? What type of InApp purchases are you using? What is the status of your inApp purchases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the Answer. My all products were in state missing metadata. All products that have to be submitted should have appropriate sufficient data set to make available to submit for review. 
(Product screenshot was missing in InApp product.)